# HTML/CSS - how do you raise up a radio button?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have a radio button that is supposed to refer to 4 images so I just put a radio button with an empty value next to the images, but when I do that, the radio button is almost lower than the bottom of the images. I want to raise it up higher so that it's in the middle of height of the images. Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="computer" value="">
<img class="extra-margin-human" width="50px" height="50px" src="images/other/human.jpg"/>
<img class="extra-margin-computer" width="50px" height="50px" src="images/other/computer.jpg"/>
<img class="extra-margin-computer" width="50px" height="50px" src="images/other/computer.jpg"/>
<img class="extra-margin-computer" width="50px" height="50px" src="images/other/computer.jpg"/>
```

How can I make the radio button come up higher?

Answer (score 1):

Apply `vertical-align:middle;` to your elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3nQUv/)

Answer (score 1):

Add position:relative to your radio button and position it using its top attribute

Here is a solution [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KnZ4Z/)

```
<input type="radio" name="computer" value="" style='position:relative; top:-20px'>
<img class="extra-margin-human" width="50px" height="50px" src="images/other/human.jpg"/>
<img class="extra-margin-computer" width="50px" height="50px" src="images/other/computer.jpg"/>
<img class="extra-margin-computer" width="50px" height="50px" src="images/other/computer.jpg"/>
<img class="extra-margin-computer" width="50px" height="50px" src="images/other/computer.jpg"/>
```

Comment: This will only work until the size of the images change.

Comment: But the OP has mentioned nothing about the dynamic change of the height of the images. Besides, all the images in the example proposed by the OP have fixed height

Comment: Yes, but even if it was done manually, there will be extra work.

Comment: Well it depends on the OP's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You could use divs, or ids.

```
<input type="radio" name="computer" value="" id="blaaah blahh blaagh">
```

And then go into CSS and do.

```
#blaah blahh blaagh{
position:absolute;
top-5px;
}
```

(This assumes that it is already inside a div, you could do `position:relative` to fix that, but then it would interfere with other elements on the webpage.)

The answer below might work better for you though.